# Error: Invalid hook call using create-react-library. Hi everyone, i cannot understand what went wrong

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, frontend

```
import React from 'react'
import './Header.css'
import SearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Search';

function Header() {
    return (
        <div className='header'>
            <h1>header</h1>

            <div className="header-input">
                <SearchIcon />
                <input type="text" />
            </div>
            
            <div className="header-icons"></div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Header;
```

Comment: you need to include a more detailed error. Where and how are you calling `Header`

Comment: God, I couldn't ask a question

Comment: You should check out here - https://stackoverflow.com/help - It has help articles on many things including how to ask a good question. As it is your question just doesnt have enough information to debug it. No biggy.

Comment: Showing the stack trace of the error would be a good starting point. This error looks like it has to do with hooks, but I don't see any hooks in the code. So my guess is that it is something in the SearchIcon code, not this header. The stack trace could confirm this, or point to something else.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it can be usefull [Error: Invalid hook call using create-react-library + MUI #18482](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/18482) . But your code hasn't got any mistake. Try to share more details